# Calculating force repulsive between a line segment and a point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, forces, integration

As shown in the diagram below, let there be a line segment $L$ and a point $p$ such that they both repel each other electrically. Let $\vec{v} = \vec{p} - \vec{q}$ be the vector from $p$ to the point on $\vec{q}$ on $L$ such that $|\vec{v}|$ is minimized (i.e. $\vec{v}$ will lie along the solid red line). The force on $p$ due to interaction with $q$ will be something like $1/|\vec{v}|^2$ (assume all constants are normalized).

[image]

However, I don't want to calculate the force on $p$ only due to $q$. I want to calculate the total force felt by $p$ due to all points on $L$ (the distance from $p$ to two other example points is denoted by dashed red lines).

It is tempting to write something like:

$$ |\vec{F}_p| = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{r(u)^2} \;\textrm{d}u$$

where $u$ is a dimensionless parameter that tells us "how far long $L$" we are, and $r(u)$ is a function that calculates the distance between some point on $L$ (parametrized by $u$) and $p$. However, there is this nasty multiplication by $\textrm{d}u$ that we don't really want, because an integration is not quite a pure summation of the integrand.

How do physicists deal with this?

Comment: Why do you say that the multiplication by d$u$ is nasty, and that you don't want it?  (You *do* want it. It represents the bit of charge at location $u$.)

Comment: Please read the tag description before tagging something with [tag:mathematical-physics].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you *do* want $\mathrm{d}u$! It's the only infinitesimal quantity in the problem. Without it, you'd be adding up an infinite number of finite quantities, and I'm not sure how you propose to meaningfully do that.

But to arrive at the justification, let's start with *finite* (but small) quantities, denoted by $\delta$'s. Then $\delta u$ represents the length of a very short segment of the line, short enough that $r(u')$ can be approximated as constant for $u \leq u' \leq u + \delta u$. This short segment can be treated as a point charge, so the force exerted by this segment on a separate charge $Q$ would be
$$\delta \vec{F} = \frac{Q\times \lambda\delta u}{r(u)^2}\hat{r}$$
and you obtain the total force by adding this up over all short segments of the line.
$$\vec{F} = \sum_\text{segments}\frac{Q\times \lambda\delta u}{r(u)^2}\hat{r}$$
Converting this to a Riemann sum yields the proper integral in the limit $\delta u\to 0$ (in which case we switch notation from $\delta u$ to $\mathrm{d}u$).